# How does this code work? Regarding pointers,string literals

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

char *fun()
{
    static char arr[1024];
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "geeksforgeeks";
    strcpy(fun(), str);
    str = fun();
    strcpy(str, "geeksquiz");
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is **geeksquiz**. Could someone help me in understanding how the code works step by step? Thank you.

Comment: This code is invoking Undefined Behaviour, so the answer is: "It works by sheer chance"

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? `fun` always returns the same pointer to the first element of the same array.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen -- I don't see anything that's undefined here. Note that `arr` is `static`, so persists outside the function call.

Comment: @Pete What about `char *str = "geeksforgeeks";`? Pretty sure it's UB in C++?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen — yes the type of the pointer should be `const char*`. That’s a hard error, not undefined behavior. It’s also enforced laxly, and it’s harmless as long as you don’t try to modify a literal string, so this code is okay in that regard.

Comment: @molbdnilo why do we write "char *fun()" but not just "char fun()" for the fun function defination? is it because it returns a string literal?

Answer (score 0):

```
static char arr[1024]; // << word static here means that every time fun() returns pointer to the same memory.

str = fun(); // now str points to that memory. 
strcpy(str, "geeksquiz"); // copies string into that memory
```